# FeatureModule fails during an AOT build when static forRoot has arguments

Tags: angular, aot

I am encountering an AOT build issue using Angular@5.1.0.

The error is:

```
ERROR in Error during template compile of 'AppModule'
  Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'FeatureModule' was called.
```

**feature.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([])
    ],
    declarations: [
        ...    
    ],
    exports: [
        ...      
    ]
})
export class FeatureModule{
    static forRoot(items:any[]): ModuleWithProviders {
        const routes:Routes = items.map(t=> {
            return { path: t.name, component: t.component };
        });

        return {
            ngModule: FeatureModule, 
            providers: [
                provideRoutes(routes)
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

This compiles successfully in non-aot builds. This seems to only be a problem for AOT builds.

Why is this error happening?

Comment: This will not solve your problem, but might maybe bring you closer to solve it. Angular 5.1 was released today along with the CLI 1.6. One of the fixed issues is `Improved decorator error messages`. Maybe try to upgrade to the latest version and see if you can find a way to solve this. Sorry for not being to help more. https://blog.angular.io/angular-5-1-more-now-available-27d372f5eb4e

Comment: thank-you, I appreciate the advice.  I'll try running CLI 1.6 to see if the errors are more informative.

Comment: The error still exists in the latest @angular/cli.

Comment: Have you tried to remove `var routes - data` and use `providers: [provideRoutes(data)]`?

Comment: In `Feature` module you wrote  `imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot() ],` shouldn't it be `forRoot([])`? Can you setup reproduction?

Comment: Yes, you're right, sorry another typo

Comment: You need to provide a reproduction of this issue. Using what you said above, I tried and can't reproduce the issue. Here's what I did (you can download this as a CLI project, run `npm install && ng build --prod` and everything works fine.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k4deww

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, it took me a while to figure this out. 
TLDR: the `forRoot` method must dead simple, otherwise the AOT compiler complains.

To make it simple, I had to:

1. Remove branching logic and function calls from the `forRoot` method.
2. Implement the logic to map the items to routes into a factory provider, rather than inlining it inside the `forRoot` method.
3. Use `Router.resetConfig` to add the routes dynamically within the factory impelmentation.
4. Add an ANALYZE_FOR_ENTRY_COMPONENTS provider so that any components passed in would be added to `entryComponents` automatically as part of the module.
5. Import `RouterModule.forChild([])` into `FeatureModule` because I use the components from `@angular/router`.
6. Import `RouterModule.forRoot([])` into `AppModule` because it provides the application-wide `Router` service.

### Final Solution

```
export const Items = new InjectionToken<any[]>('items');
export function InitMyService(router:Router, items:any[]) {
     var routes:Routes =  items.map(t=> { return { path: t.name, component: t.component, outlet: 'modal' }});
     var r = router.config.concat(routes);
     router.resetConfig(r);        
     return new MyService(router);
}


@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        RouterModule.forChild([])
    ],
    declarations: [
        MyComponent
    ],
    exports: [
        MyComponent
    ],
    providers: [

    ]
})
export class FeatureModule {
    static forRoot(items:any[]): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
            ngModule: FeatureModule, 
            providers: [
                { provide: Items, useValue: items},
                { provide: ANALYZE_FOR_ENTRY_COMPONENTS, multi: true, useValue: items},
                { provide: MyService, useFactory: InitMyService, deps:[Router, Items] }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ 
      BrowserModule,
      RouterModule.forRoot([]),
      FeatureModule.forRoot([{name: 'test', component: TestComponent}])
    ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, TestComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  providers: [
  ],
  exports: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

The key to solving this was the realization that `RouterModule.forChild()` does not register any router services. This is intentional so that any module can import the RouterModule and take advantage of its components, without actually registering any services.  At the AppModule level, I still needed to register the `Router` service as a singleton by importing `RouterModule.forRoot()` into AppModule.

Comment: Can you share your MyService class?