# Function calls are not supported in decorators while ng build --prod (AOT)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-aot, angular-universal, ng-packagr

Type of Issue: Bug / Question

Description

I'm using ng-packagr lib to compile my library to js. I've compiled everything without any problems, but when I'll want to consume my library with ng build --prod (AOT enabled), I'm getting error:

`ERROR in Error during template compile of 'AppModule' Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'BsDropdownModule' was called.`

When I remove .forRoot method, I'm getting error:

`ERROR in : Unexpected value 'BsDropdownModule in /home/sf/Desktop/Developerka/kompilacja/final/sample-repo/node_modules/angular-library-name/free/dropdown/dropdown.module.d.ts' imported by the module 'AppModule in /home/sf/Desktop/Developerka/kompilacja/final/sample-repo/src/app/app.module.ts'. Please add a @NgModule annotation`

Please note, that `ng --prod --aot=false`
is not producing any errors.

How To Reproduce:

Download repo: https://github.com/Bloodcast69/aot-error , type 
`npm install
ng build --prod.`

Expected Behaviour

Want to build with AOT without errors (I need this to be compatible with Angular Universal)
Version Information

`ng-packagr: 2.4.1
@angular/*: 5.2.9
typescript: 2.5.3
rxjs: 5.5.6
node: 8.1.0
npm/yarn: npm: 5.6.0`

Files:

app.module.ts:

```
import { BsDropdownModule } from 'angular-library-name';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';



import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BsDropdownModule.forRoot(),
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

dropdown.module.d.ts:

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
export declare class BsDropdownModule {
    static forRoot(config?: any): ModuleWithProviders;
}
```

dropdown.module.ts (before compilation to JS):

```
import { ModuleWithProviders, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ComponentLoaderFactory } from '../utils/component-loader/index';

import { PositioningService } from '../utils/positioning/index';
import { BsDropdownContainerComponent } from './dropdown-container.component';
import { BsDropdownMenuDirective } from './dropdown-menu.directive';
import { BsDropdownToggleDirective } from './dropdown-toggle.directive';
import { BsDropdownConfig } from './dropdown.config';

import { BsDropdownDirective } from './dropdown.directive';
import { BsDropdownState } from './dropdown.state';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  BsDropdownMenuDirective,
  BsDropdownToggleDirective,
  BsDropdownContainerComponent,
  BsDropdownDirective
  ],
  exports: [
  BsDropdownMenuDirective,
  BsDropdownToggleDirective,
  BsDropdownDirective
  ],
  entryComponents: [BsDropdownContainerComponent]
})
export class BsDropdownModule {
  public static forRoot(config?: any): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: BsDropdownModule, providers: [
      ComponentLoaderFactory,
      PositioningService,
      BsDropdownState,
      {provide: BsDropdownConfig, useValue: config ? config : {autoClose: true}}
      ]
    };
  };
}
```

**NOTE**
I've read whole Internet to find something which would be helpful to me, but without any success. I've checked this topics:

[FeatureModule fails during an AOT build when static forRoot has arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47686638/featuremodule-fails-during-an-aot-build-when-static-forroot-has-arguments)

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14707

If there's missing some needed informations, please let me know, and I'll provide it.

Thanks,
Bloodcast69

Comment: BsDropdownModule is in node_modules/angular-library-name/free/dropdown 
You have to npm install to see it. This module is after compilation to js.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Please try now, I've added angular-library-name-5.2.3.tgz file and added it to dependencies. Download fresh repo and type npm i

Comment: @yurzui could you describe this using more words?

Comment: Okay I'll test it and let you know if it's working or not.

Comment: It was something else. I had to point exact path for some providers. For example not import { service } from './services' but import { service } from './services/sample.service. But thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Did you only remote the index.ts from the services folder or from all the components?

Answer (score 2):

It's a problem with AOT: the `forRoot` function needs to be executed at compile-time. On a more recent version of Angular it should work as-is, otherwise you might have luck playing with `tsconfig.app.json`. Check this related question: [Angular 6 Prod Function calls are not supported in decorators but '..Module' was called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51475871/angular-6-prod-function-calls-are-not-supported-in-decorators-but-module-was/52016077)

Answer (score 0):

Your `forRoot` method should return  `ModuleWithProviders` and annotated with `@NgModule`

```
  import { ModuleWithProviders, NgModule } from '@angular/core';

    @NgModule({
        declarations: [],
        imports: [],
        providers: [],

      })
    export class BsDropdownModule {
       // constructor(parentModule: BsDropdownModule);
        //  static forRoot(config?: any): ModuleWithProviders;
        static forRoot(config?: any): ModuleWithProviders {

            return {
                ngModule: BsDropdownModule,
                providers: [
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

So, you should import `dropdown.module` in `app.module` not the declaration file `dropdown.module.d.ts`

```
import { BsDropdownModule } from './dropdown.module';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BsDropdownModule.forRoot(),
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I tested with `AOT` build. No error

Comment: The code you entered is included in the module which is not yet compiled to .js. The compiled module only contains the code that I've pasted, and for some reason the code doesn't work after compilation - it throws away an error that I've pasted above.

Please check my dropdown.module.ts code which I've posted above.

Comment: `import { BsDropdownModule } from 'angular-library-name';` Is it dropdown.module.ts ? `angular-library-name`

Comment: import { BsDropdownModule } from 'angular-library-name';


is compiled to js module. While importing this module to my app.module, I'm unable to call forRoot() method on it while AOT. If something isn't clear to you, maybe try to download my repo and look at code?

Answer (score -1):

I am facing the same issue as well, I was able to narrow it to ng-packagr. 
I extracted my module out of the library and tested in separate application I didn't face any AOT errors. I only get this error when I package my module in a library

I am using Angular 6.1.8 and ng-packagr 4.2.0

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. I know you don't have earned the commentary privilege, but this doesn't help to solve the problem