# Dynamic Setting of the Router

Tags: angular, angular-router, contentful

I have an Angular 5 app that retrieves content from Contentful. Some of this content is routes. I would like to set these inside a child `RoutingModule` as follows:

```
const myRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: BaseComponent },
  { path: '**', component: FailComponent }
];

@NgModule({ 
  RouterModule.forChild(myRoutes),
  ... 
})

export class MyRoutingModule {
  routesFromContentful = retrieveRoutesFromContentful();
  routes.forEach((route:string) => {
    myRoutes.push({ path: route, component: GenericComponent }); 
  }
}
```

To be clear:

1. I am mapping all routes to the same component, `GenericComponent`. This is intended.
2. I have no problem retrieving the routes from Contentful.
3. The issue is that the new routes I push into `myRoutes` are not recognized.

Is there a way to have these routes recognized? Are they not recognized because the exported class comes after `@NgModule`?

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47686638/featuremodule-fails-during-an-aot-build-when-static-forroot-has-arguments

Comment: Thank you! Very interesting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For pushing routes to current route configuration, you could push those routes in by calling [`resetConfig`](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#resetConfig) method on `router` dependency instance like below.

```
export class MyRoutingModule {
  constructor(private router: Router){
     this.loadRoutes();
  }

  loadRoutes(){
     routesFromContentful = retrieveRoutesFromContentful();
     routes.forEach((route:string) => {
        myRoutes.push({ path: route, component: GenericComponent }); 
     }
     //reseting router configuration
     this.router.resetConfig(routes);
  } 
}
```

or You can directly push new routes inside `router.config` object.

```
export class MyRoutingModule {
  constructor(private router: Router){
     this.loadRoutes();
  }

  loadRoutes(){
     routesFromContentful = retrieveRoutesFromContentful();
     routes.forEach((route:string) => {
        //adding routes to existing to configuration.
        this.router.config.push({ path: route, component: GenericComponent }); 
     }
  } 
}
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much! I wasn't expecting two answers haha!

Comment: @AlexVerzea I tried covering every possible way, thanks mate ;)

Comment: Suppose that you have a situation where the router is actually a child router. You also need to use the ** route at the end for an error page. The solution you gave would fail as the extra routes would be added after the ** one and lead to the error page. Would it be possible to change it for that?

Comment: Also, I get an error for the `GenericComponent` when I try to add it as above:

`Error: No component factory found for GenericComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?`

The component is already added to the `declarations` and `entryComponents`, to no effect.

Comment: @AlexVerzea for your 1st comment you can easily pluck `error` route, and put it at the end of `routes` array.

Comment: @AlexVerzea I don't understand your second comment, where `GenericComponent` resides?

Comment: @Panjak Parkar: I don't understand what you mean by the `error` route. Everywhere I looked, people use the `'**'` route to set the error. For the structure, I have a `GenericParentComponent`, which has the `GenericComponent` as a child. The above code is for the `MyRoutingModule`, which has both `GenericParentComponent` and `GenericComponent` inside `declarations`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168745/discussion-between-pankaj-parkar-and-alex-verzea).